# jquery form validation not fired / working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do a very basic form validation, and my method of choice is jQuery. However, for some reason, the validation function seems not to get fired at all.

After looking at this for several hours I can't find out what the problem is.

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="process.php">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="160">Meno:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="meno" id="meno" /></td>
        <td width="160">Priezvisko:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="priezvisko" id="priezvisko" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="160">Názov spolocnosti: <br />
          <span class="register_comment">(nevyplnajte ak nie ste podnikatel)</span></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="spolocnost" id="spolocnost" /></td>
        <td width="160">Krajina:</td>
        <td><select name="krajina" id="krajina">
          <option value="" selected="selected">&nbsp;</option>
          <option value="cz">Ceská republika</option>
          <option value="sk">Slovenská republika</option>
        </select></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="160">Adresa:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="adresa" id="adresa" /></td>
        <td width="160">Mesto:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mesto" id="mesto" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="160">Email:<br />
          <span class="register_comment">(na tento email Vám príde potvrdenie)</span></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
        <td width="160">Telefonický kontakt:<br />
          <span class="register_comment">(uvádzajte kontakt na mobilný telefón na ktorom budete zastihnutelní najmä 10.10.!)</span></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="telefon" id="telefon" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="160">Miesto nástupu: </td>
        <td colspan="3"><select name="nastup" id="nastup">
          <option value="" selected="selected">&nbsp;</option>
          <option value="nr">Nitra</option>
          <option value="ba">Bratislava</option>
          <option value="br">Brno - Avion Shopping Park, Škandinávská 128/2</option>
          <option value="ph">Praha - Avion Shopping Park, Škandinávská 15/A</option>
          <option value="pl">Plzen - OC Olympia, Písecká 972/1</option>
        </select></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><p>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="suhlas" value="checkbox" id="suhlas" />
            Oboznámil som sa s podmienkami úcasti a Súhlasím s podmienkami úcasti  </label>
          FLEX Polishing Camp<br />
        </p></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="submit" id="button" value="Odoslat záväznú prihlášku na FLEX Polishing Camp" style="width:500px;" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="register_comment">xxxx</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>  
    $("#form1").submit(function() {
      var errors = new array();
      if ($('input[name=meno]').val() == "") {
        errors.push('Meno je povinná položka.');
      }
      if ($('input[name=priezvisko]').val() == "") {
        errors.push('Priezvisko je povinná položka.');
      }
      if ($('input[name=krajina]').val() == "") {
        errors.push('Je nutné vybrať si krajinu - ČR alebo SR.');
      }
      if ($('input[name=adresa]').val() == "") {
        errors.push('Adresa je povinná položka.');
      }
      if ($('input[name=mesto]').val() == "") {
        errors.push('Mesto je povinná položka.');
      }
      if ($('input[name=email]').val() == "") {
        errors.push('Email je povinná položka.');
      }
      if ($('input[name=telefon]').val() == "") {
        errors.push('Telefonický kontakt je povinná položka.');
      }
      if ($('input[name=nastup]').val() == "") {
        errors.push('Telefonický kontakt je povinná položka.');
      }
      if (!$('#suhlas').attr('checked')) {
        errors.push('Je potrebné vysloviť súhlas s podmienkami zaškrtnutím tlačítka "Oboznámil som sa s podmienkami účasti a Súhlasím s podmienkami účasti FLEX Polishing Camp".');
      }
      if ( errors.lenght > 0 )
      {
        var text;
        for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
            text = text + errors[i] + '\n';
        };
        alert(text);
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `var errors = new array();` should be `var errors = new Array();`, but I would use `var errors = [];`

Comment: `if ( errors.lenght > 0 )` should be `if ( errors.length > 0 )`

Comment: I would use `var text = errors.join("\n");` instead of the `for` loop at the end to combine the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other mention you have missed the `#` for your ID selector, you can also use `map` method and minify your code.

```
$("#form1").submit(function() {
      var errors = [];
      errors = $('input[type=text]', this).filter(function(){
            return $.trim(this.value) == "";
      }).map(function() {
            return this.name + ' je povinná položka.';
      }).get();

      if (errors.length) {
           var text = errors.join('\n');
           alert(text);
           return false;
      }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bwVWQ/

Comment: thank you very much for this idea, however, there are special characters (diacritics) in the alert messages, without them they are grammatically incorrect... however - the main problem is that the function is not fired at submit at all...

Comment: @Michal The alerted message in jsfiddle is grammatically incorrect? What makes it correct, for the second issue, please check the fiddle, submit event fires there. There should be an error elsewhere in your other codes, any error on the console?

Comment: I have checked it and I have modified your code, it works now. I can't name the error though... But I would suppose it was due to the last IF statement...

Comment: @Michal Yes there is a typo there `lenght` should be `length`.

Comment: Oh - and grammatically makes it for example "spolocnost", taken from the input name. However, it is missing special chars, correctly it is "Spoločnosť"...

Comment: @Michal Oe, you can modify your input's name value.

Comment: Well, incl special characters? Not sure if that is an good idea? `<input type="text" name="Spoločnosť" id="spolocnost" />`??

Comment: @Michal Alternatively yon use `data-*` attributes and use `$(this).data('name')` instead of `this.name`.

Comment: hmm... interesting... gonna try it out next time :) I am glad that this works finally... thought it was a 30mins job and I already spent 4 hours on it...

Answer (score 2):

$("form1") should be $("#form1")

Comment: I have updated the code, however, the problem persists... (code in question updated too)

Answer (score 1):

```
First $("form1")  should be $("#form1")
```

//Secondly

```
 text = text + arr[i] + '\n';
```

//Should be

```
 text = text + errors[i] + '\n';   OR   text += errors[i] + '\n';
```

Looks like the Updated code has again a typo  in it..
This might be preventing it

```
if ( errors.lenght > 0 )    // Supposed to be  errors.length
```

Comment: I have updated the code, however, the problem persists... (code in question updated too) - btw thanx for the typo, I have corrected that too...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `#` sign on your selector, `#form1`

```
$("#form1").submit(function() {
```